# Npm Publish Issue - Artifactory

Tags: npm, artifactory, publish

I am publishing an npm library to an npm repo on artifactory. The library is built using angular and the dist folder and package.json looks correct. When publishing, the request it's self is published but not the actual artifact.

All i see on artifactory is a single file and not a folder containing my package

Running
`npm publish`

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "@abce/embedded-auth",
  "version": "1.0.0-dev.0",
  "main": "bundles/abce-auth.umd.js",
  "module": "fesm5/abce-auth.js",
  "es2015": "fesm2015/abce-auth.js",
  "esm5": "esm5/abce-auth.js",
  "esm2015": "esm2015/abce-auth.js",
  "fesm5": "fesm5/abce.js",
  "fesm2015": "fesm2015/abce-auth.js",
  "typings": "abce-auth.d.ts",
  "metadata": "abce-auth.metadata.json",
  "sideEffects": false,
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^1.9.0"
  }
}
```

What actually gets published to artifactory in a single file.

```
{
    "_id": "@abce/embedded-auth",
    "name": "@abce/embedded-auth",
    "dist-tags": {
        "latest": "1.0.0-dev.1"
    },
    "versions": {
        "1.0.0-dev.1": {
            "name": "@abce/embedded-auth",
            "version": "1.0.0-dev.1",
            "main": "bundles/abce-auth.umd.js",
            "module": "fesm5/abce-auth.js",
            "es2015": "fesm2015/abce-auth.js",
            "esm5": "esm5/abce-auth.js",
            "esm2015": "esm2015/abce-auth.js",
            "fesm5": "fesm5/abce-auth.js",
            "fesm2015": "fesm2015/abce-auth.js",
            "typings": "abce-auth.d.ts",
            "metadata": "abce-auth.metadata.json",
            "sideEffects": false,
            "dependencies": {
                "tslib": "^1.9.0"
            },
            "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
            "_id": "@abce/embedded-auth@1.0.0-dev.1",
            "_npmVersion": "6.4.1",
            "_nodeVersion": "10.15.3",
            "_npmUser": {
                "name": "deployment",
                "email": "bob@bob.ie"
            },
            "maintainers": [
                {
                    "name": "deployment",
                    "email": "bob@bob.ie"
                }
            ],
            "dist": {
                "integrity": "sha512-rpTN1sMpwnMwehzWUqbV+zElzaOlF5ekQRCQMncy6c+i4TAp5jbBobvzrhgl0ORqHgJn3Eo+EcrRgYLSjV7MdQ==",
                "shasum": "71f654dd5fddb20a9d5063171d5293424a4271c7",
                "tarball": "http://abce.jfrog.io/abce/internal-npm-dev/@abce/embedded-auth/-/@abce/embedded-auth-1.0.0-dev.1.tgz"
            }
        }
    },
    "readme": "ERROR: No README data found!",
    "maintainers": [
        {
            "name": "deployment",
            "email": "bob@bob.ie"
        }
    ],
    "_attachments": {
        "@abce/embedded-auth-1.0.0-dev.1.tgz": {
            "content_type": "application/octet-stream",
            "data": "correctly populated tarball base64 data here. I checked it and it is correct",
            "length": 12092
        }
    }
}
```

Expect:
I would expect the package to be parsed from the request and the package published correctly

Actual:
The put request data from the npm publish command is published as a file

npm version: 6.9.0
node version: v12.3.1(has also been run with 10.15.3)

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see any related errors in the Artifactory log file? are you able to resolve the package from Artifactory?

Comment: no i am not able to resolve the package. i will check the logs :-(

Answer (score 1):

Please check the registry URL that you are using from npm, if it doesn't include `/api/npm` - it is invalid.

Wrong URL: `https://domain/artifactory/some-directory/`.
Valid URL: `https://domain/artifactory/api/npm/some-directory/`.

Comment: Just wasted hours of my time trying to publish my first package to private artifactory.. I was searching from the wrong places. This worked! Thanks!